# Using INSERT INTO for ascii / external files?

Tags: sql, postgresql, relational-database

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Bulk Insert of hundreds of millions of records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2842409/bulk-insert-of-hundreds-of-millions-of-records)

So I was just wondering if it was possible to use INSERT INTO for, say a 700k row external ascii file into a table that's already created and with existing data in it? Al values are the same, it's just that a colleague of mine told me to use that command instead of COPY. Is this comment false?

Thanks in advance.

PS: I'm using PosgtreSQL /PGAdmin III

Comment: Don't know about COPY, I'm just thinking it might be easier to do this programmatically.

Also, you've got to be careful with your field types. I'm not that knowledgable on Postgre, but I know in mySQL I came up against issues a while ago where I was trying to save megabytes of data to a TEXT column, which didn't work because of data size restrictions.

Comment: If by possible you mean editing the file to make it a `SQL` script file then yes it is possible. Why would you do it in instead of using `copy`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also map your text file as a table using a foreign data wrapper:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/file-fdw.html

Two examples:

http://michael.otacoo.com/postgresql-2/postgresql-playing-with-foreign-data-wrappers-1/
http://www.depesz.com/2011/03/14/waiting-for-9-1-foreign-data-wrapper/

Once you have mapped the text file to a table, you can do a

```
INSERT INTO target_table (col1, col2, col3)
SELECT col1, col2, col3 
FROM fdw_table;
```

Answer (score 0):

Technically if your file is well formatted like:

```
(f1, f2, f3, f4),
```

You could simply prepend:

```
INSERT INTO tbs(f1, f2, f3, f4) VALUES
```

In the beginning of the file terminate everything with a `;` and try running it as a single SQL command.  Problem is with 700k rows I don't even know if PostgreSQL will even be able to parse a statement this long.  My money is that it won't but you are welcome to try.  For more documentation see [this page](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/sql-insert.html).

Now if you are bent on not using `COPY` then I would look into writing a simple Perl or Python script that would do the following:

```
while(<FILE>)
{
    chomp;
    @data_fields = split(/<delim>/, $_);
    $sth->execute(@data_fields);
}
```

Where `$sth` is the `INSERT` statement prepared against the database.